# Error linking with mingw compiler using Codelite, can't find lib folder

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, codelite

I'm trying to get started with SDL and trying to compile a 'hello world' starter app to check my configuration and I get this error:

`C:/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/g++.exe -c "C:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/Demo_Graphics/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -IC:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/include
C:/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/g++.exe  -o ./Debug/Demo_Graphics @"Demo_Graphics.txt" -L.  -lC:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/`


`c:/mingw-4.8.1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/`


`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/Demo_Graphics] Error 1
Demo_Graphics.mk:79: recipe for target 'Debug/Demo_Graphics' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/Demo_Graphics'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
1 errors, 0 warnings`

The directory `C:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/` certainly does exist and has the required SDL libraries in it, but I have no clue about compilers.
This is predefined code which should work so the problem is in set up somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -l compiler flag is adding a library dependency. It does **not** specify a path in which to look for libraries (that is the -L flag), which appears to be what you are expecting.

In your error message:

```
-L.  -lC:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/
```

You can see that the compiler is looking in your current working directory (.) for the library *C:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/*, but this is not a library -- this is the directory in which you're storing the SDL libraries.

In the CodeLite linker setup you want to change your library path to C:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/, or use

```
-LC:/Users/Me/Documents/Cpp_Projects/SDL2/32bit/lib/
```

as a build flag.

You also need to link to the SDL2 library, so you'll need to add -lSDL2 (possibly -lSDL2main as well, I can't remember the specifics of the SDL libraries) to your build/linker flags.

Comment: Thankyou, exactly what I needed. For reference for others using Codelite.  Be aware of two linker entries 'Search Path' for path and 'Libraries' for actual libraries (obvious once you see it!).  SDL in CodeLite requires the entry in libraries to read `mingw32;SDL2;SDL2main` assuming 32bit executable.